# Checked solution into TFS, references break on second machine

Tags: tfs, asp.net-4.5

I've been working on a web application (ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms), and then added it to TFS to make the source code accessible to the client. I had no trouble getting it added to TFS, but when I got latest on a different machine (than the one I developed on) to test if TFS was working, I'm running into a bunch of reference errors to basic things like EntityFramework, Microsoft.ScriptManager, System.Web.Optimization. A client has run into the same issue when he checked out.

The thing is, if I create a new web application project on this machine, it has all those same references, but they're working correctly.

I've seen suggestions to add the actual DLLs to the project in a /lib folder, then reference them instead, but I don't think that's the right course of action for these basic, built-in assemblies.

One more thing- when I publish to Azure, it works just fine.

Any clue how I can get these references working properly?

Full list of broken references:

```
- AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery
- AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery.IO.Combined
- EntityFramework
- Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth
- Microsoft.Aspnet.Web.Optimization.WebForms
- Microsofot.ScriptManager.MSAjax
- Microsoft.ScriptManager.WebForms
- System.Web.Optimization
```

EDIT: I finally got this figured out. Apparently even these key assemblies are generated into the "packages" folder where the project is located. I added this folder to source control and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on one of the references (on your machine) select properties, then check the full path to where the assemblies are located.

If they are in a folder called packages under your solution then they are NuGet packages not built in assemblies.  Which means you either need to check the packages folder into source control, or right click the solution and enable package restore mode.

If they are program files then they aren't really built in assemblies either, they're likely installed by something else you installed onto that machine.